Python3 extract various subsets from list/array into a single new variable
In matlab for an 1xM array let us say a=1,1.5,2,2.5,...10

a=1:0.5:10;

one can easily extract several subsets of the array in 1 line of code
b=a([1:3 10:13]);.
making b=1,1.5,2,5.5,6,6.5,7. If one would like to achieve something equivalent in python3 and numpy, what is the recommended approach? Note the actual vector is of length 1 x 7 and the subsets to extract are of different lengths and random initial and final indexes.

@destructioneer I don't think your edit that changed "1e7" to "1x7" makes sense. Sure, OP's given example has 7 elements, but I think what they wanted to say is that their actual data has 1e7 = 10^7 = 10,000,000 elements.

@simon Maybe you are right. At the time 1 x 7  seemed more reasonable to me, due to the sample vector size.

I guess it doesn't matter that much, anyway :D No worries!

Here is a short answer to that, live from Python in CLI, without numpy:
# generate your vector a, as only integers are allowed in range()
>>> b=[x*0.5 for x in range(2,21)]
>>> b
[1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5, 10.0]

# compose result subset from subsets
>>> b=a[1:4]+a[10:14]
>>> b
[1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5]

Depending on your indexes and limits, the respective final answer can be taken also by using these b=a[start_index:(start_index+4)]+a[end_index:(end_index+4)]

This is good for regular Python .
Another option would be to use operator.itemgetter which can take an (* prefixed)  sequence of slices to extract those from any sequence. For numpy backed data, one better check the answer by  @simon

Personally, I would use numpy.r_ for concatenating Numpy arrays. You can use it in two ways (see use case 1 and 2 in its documentation, corresponding to b and c below):
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(1, 10, num=19)  # 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, …, 10.

b = np.r_[a[0:3], a[9:13]]      # Use case 1: concatenation of arrays
c = a[np.r_[0:3, 9:13]]         # Use case 2: concatenation of indices

print(b)  # >>> [1.  1.5 2.  5.5 6.  6.5 7. ]
print(c)  # >>> [1.  1.5 2.  5.5 6.  6.5 7. ]

Note the different indexing as compared to Matlab (indexing is zero-based, upper bound is exclusive).
There are several alternatives or variations, e.g. you can also use slice() for the array bounds:
d = np.r_[a[slice(0, 3)], a[slice(9, 13)]]
e = a[np.r_[slice(0, 3), slice(9, 13)]]

I don't know your exact use case. In general, I would prefer options b or c though.
Update: Also, be careful with + and Numpy arrays: While @destructioneer's answer would work with native Python sequences (e.g. lists and tuples), it would not work with Numpy arrays, as + is defined as elementwise summation rather than concatenation for the latter.
For a varying quantity of slices:
Also, as you mention you will get arbitrary slices, Python syntax allows for that. If you have your ranges in a list, for example slices = [slice(0, 3), slice(9, 13)] you can do:
slices = [slice(0, 3), slice(9, 13)] 
f = a[np.r_[*slices]]

Note the asterisk *, which unpacks the slices list, which means you effectively write the same as in option e above.

Hi - I find this answer to be almost perfect, but it would be missing O.P. s need to operate with varying slices during runtime. I took the freedom to add such an example at the bottom - please, feel free to re-edit as you like.

Hi @jsbueno: Thanks a lot, I missed that part of the question!

@jsbueno I am not sure, if the result works as you intend: If you write slices = [(0, 3), (10, 13), (20, 23)], you will get elements at index 0, 3, 10, 13, 20, 23. You will not get the index ranges 0:3, 10:13, 20:23. Did you mean slices = [slice(0, 3), slice(10, 13), slice(20, 23)]?

Anyway, I hope I fixed your addition. Feel free to double-check and adjust again. Just to clarify again: If you write slices = [(0, 3), (10, 13), (20, 23)] and np.r_[*slices], you effectively write np.r_[(0, 3), (10, 13), (20, 23)] – which will simply result in a concatenation of the values in the tuples (so [0, 3, 10, 13, 20, 23]) but not in an expansion into ranges.

Yes - the tuples should be explicit slice objects - your edition seems to work. thanks. (I tested it, but did not notice it had just used the numbers inside the tuples as indices rather than the tuples as ranges)
